# Making an action in jquery target a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on my website and I'm trying to do a blog section. I have two div's resting inside a parent div in my html. Both divs share the same class selector. I'm using jquery to hide the text inside of them until hovered over. But since they have the same class selector when you hover over one div it shows the text in both. How do I keep them in the same class but only show the text in the div that's currently being hovered over?

HTML:

```
<div class="mythoughts">
    <div class="date">15FEB2014</div>
    <div class="entry">
        <p class="vis">Blah ...</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mythoughts">
    <div class="date">16FEB2014</div>
    <div class="entry">
        <p class="div">Blah ...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.mythoughts').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.entry').show();
});

$('.mythoughts').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.entry').hide();
});
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this` (which refers to the current item) to get the correct element.

Change this code:

```
$('.mythoughts').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.entry').show();  // shows ALL .entry elements (not desired)
});
```

to

```
$('.mythoughts').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find('.entry').show();  // shows .entry within the hovered .mythoughts
});
```

Your code:  http://jsfiddle.net/29VkS/

Updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/29VkS/1/

Comment: This is perfect! I've been teaching myself and for some reason couldn't figure this out. Would upvote if I had more reputation... Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help.  While you can't upvote, be sure to click the checkbox next to the most helpful answer to accept that answer as the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

"But since they have the same class selector when you hover over one div it shows the text in both."

Why don't you differentiate your divs with different IDs?

```
<div class="sameclass" id="firstdiv"></div>
<div class="sameclass" id="seconddiv"></div>
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an id for the div

```
<div id="unique_id" class="the_same_class">...</div>
```

The id can be called by Jquery